# Как создать аккаунт google play console для студии?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

Мы с моим другом создали приложение и планируем его опубликовать, возможно ли средствами google play console сделать так, чтобы мы были с равными права или все равно у кого-то будут привелегии? Возможно ли дать права создателя или он только один? Как правильно на ваш взгляд организвать регистрацию небольшой студии, состоящей из двух и более человек, в GP?

Comment: у кого-то будут привилегии, а как иначе? Один владелец, другой дает доступ и назначает права

Comment: @Style-7, понял спасибо!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В **Google Play Console** возможно устроить равноправие (Администратор) над приложением, или же дать права, но с ограничением. Для этого нужно просто прислать сгенерированное приглашение напарнику(ам) по эл. почте, как видно на картинке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*P.S. Платить напарнику(ам) не нужно, просто иметь эл. почту.*